Selenium Java: no such element: Unable to locate element:
Hi There I am getting "no such element: Unable to locate element error", it's been running successfully all of sudden I am seeing this issue nothing has changed from UI side same elements.I tried with different elements same issue even I tried to run other test suites same issue, even though element is present getting an error "no such element: Unable to locate element error"
Code ' {Using=xpath, value=//div[@role='button']}' I tried this also '@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='team-name']")' still same error.
System Info: Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'xxxxxxxx', ip: 'xxxxxxx:3f50:0:0:0:1dc8%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '11.3', java.version: '11.0.11'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 127.0.6533.120, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 127.0.6533.119 (bdef6783a05..., userDataDir: /var/folders/2r/npm5q39d6gj...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:65147}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}

You need to add some delay to get the element to be available. I think it is related to timeout reason.

you should probably be using webdriverwaits with expected conditions, a better locator, and version 4 of Selenium.  It's actually sort of strange that you can run chromedriver at all with 3.141.59

I have added a wait and even sleep also nothing has worked.

you should update Selenium to latest version.  (at least 4.x)

I have updated java-selenium v to 4.11.0, still facing same issue.

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='team-name']"}
(Session info: chrome=128.0.6613.36)
Build info: version: '4.11.0', System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '11.3', java.version: '11.0.11'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [b858bcd0e70fb42075e666d84e7270f6, findElement {using=xpath, value=//div[@class='team-name']}]

I created a new project and used same xpath, it worked able to click on it, but same  xpath is not working in my original project. I think this issue may not related to xpath unable to find the root cause.  working code. 'public class BrowserLaunch {
public static void main(String[] args) {
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://***********.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='team-name']")).click();
driver.quit();
}
}'
